# git layout for project with library dependencies?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Hello this is the scenario I want help with.

I have two projects on [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) (similar to [github](http://github.com)). One is a an application the other is a Library. So while I'm working on the application I want to be able to submit patches to the library (I want to keep them separated with different branches). The application is also dependent on this Library.

The layout on disk might look something like this:

```
$MyProject/Src
$MyProject/Library
```

I Want to be able to submit patches and branch them independently, can I use git subtree, or should I go with git submodules?

Is there a third alternative that is even better?

Comment: git submodules seem good. However many platforms have dependency managers which are (as for me) easier to use like Apache Maven or CocoaPods. They are not alternatives to git, but they allow you to organize your libraries like separate git repos and add dependencies to them into your main project.

Comment: IMO, git submodules become a pain, just move to using subtree. It would work just fine.

Comment: Care to elaborate a little? Why do git submodules become a pain? Can I easily push changes from the subtree to "origin develop" of that repository?

Comment: Why submodules may become a pain: http://somethingsinistral.net/blog/git-submodules-are-probably-not-the-answer/

Comment: @gturri I stopped reading that link after the first section.  Everything I read was either flat wrong or wrong by omission.

Comment: I ended up with using a subtree for the time being. I will look into using CocoaPods in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is just me but i personally use google repo(python scripts using git for massive repository numbers) instead of submodules.

Maybe it is worth investigating for you. You only need to define a xml with your origins, branches git repostories etc and repo does the rest.

You could then easily define your folder structure as you like or switch to another branch combination.

Answer (score 1):

A third alternative could be:

- put the application and the library in separate repositories
- publish package of your library whenever you want
- have your application reference the version of the library you want.

An advantage is that you won't need to try to do fancy stuff with Git.

Two drawbacks would be that:

- if you don't package / distribute your library yet, it may require some additional work to put in place
- if a change in your library breaks your application, you may not notice it immediately (but you would likely have the same issue with submodules)